# Android studio не запоминает свернутые методы

Tags: android-studio

Столкнулся с проблемой: при работе сворачиваю не нужные мне в данный момент методы, а после того как перезапущу Android studio она не запоминает то что было свернуто и разворачивает весь код. Как можно настроить чтобы Android studio запоминала, то что я свернул?

Comment: Это не проблема. Нормальное поведение оболочки. Но тоже интересно

Comment: Проблема - в смысле моя проблема.